# phpMyAdmin error #1064

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Trying to import stored procedures created in my local machine into a web server (iPage hosting) by using phpMyAdmin.

Due to errors in the process of importing the procedures I decided to manually enter the stored procedures using scripts into the server, like the following example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upvote(IN _message_id int, IN _user_id int)
BEGIN
DECLARE qty_upvotes INT;

INSERT IGNORE INTO upvotes SET message_id = _message_id,user_id = _user_id;

SET qty_upvotes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upvotes WHERE message_id = _message_id);

UPDATE message_stats
SET upvotes = qty_upvotes
WHERE message_id = _message_id;

END
```

Then I get the error below.

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I looked for it everywhere since 2 days now and I cannot find a solution.

Any clue?

Comment: Did you try to wrap all the properties and values with `\`` such as `\`message_id\` = \`_message_id\`,\`user_id\` = \`_user_id\``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got feedback from my hosting provider about the issue:

> Unfortunately 'stored procedures' and 'stored routines' are not supported in our platform. I suggest you to install latest version of phpmyadmin to your account which supports these options.